# How can I change the location of Bootstrap Table Paginator?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am using [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) source CSS. I'd like to move the text and page size like the following from the bottom of the table to the top. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLp7M.png).

> Showing 1 to 20 of 159 rows [20] rows per page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the code on https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/welcome.html

Move the location of this div:

```
<div class="float-left pagination-detail">
      <span class="pagination-info">
      Showing 1 to 10 of 800 rows
      </span><span class="page-list"><span class="btn-group dropdown dropup">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="page-size">
        10
        </span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">10</a><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">25</a><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">50</a><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">100</a><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">All</a></div></span> rows per page</span></div>
```

move it after:

```
<div class="bs-bars float-left"><div id="toolbar">
  <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete
  </button>
</div></div>
```

instead of its original location, which is inside `<div class="fixed-table-pagination">...</div>`

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't the answer I wanted.

I was inquiring about how to change the CSS setting.I asked you about how you can change it to an option because it automatically imports the function when you import Table Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `paginationVAlign` setting:

- [Documentation for `paginationVAlign`](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#paginationvalign)
- [Demo for `paginationVAlign`](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/pagination-v-align.html)

Use it by setting `data-pagination-v-align` on your table element to `"top"`, `"bottom"` or `"both"`. The alignment of the pagination widget will be adjusted based on this.